# Stack installing cairo for threadscope

Tags: haskell, cabal, cairo, haskell-stack, threadscope

I started installing threadscope through stack (rather than cabal, is that OK? https://wiki.haskell.org/ThreadScope).  threadscope requires cairo.

```
$ stack install cairo
cairo-0.13.3.1: configure

--  While building package cairo-0.13.3.1 using:
      /home/username/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc --make -odir /tmp/stack13291/cairo-0.13.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup -hidir /tmp/stack13291/cairo-0.13.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup -i -i. -package=Cabal-1.24.2.0 -clear-package-db -global-package-db -package-db=/home/username/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-7.10/8.0.1/pkgdb /tmp/stack13291/cairo-0.13.3.1/Setup.hs /home/username/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -o /tmp/stack13291/cairo-0.13.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup -threaded
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/username/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/cairo-0.13.3.1.log

    [1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack13291/cairo-0.13.3.1/Setup.hs, /tmp/stack13291/cairo-0.13.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/Main.o )

    /tmp/stack13291/cairo-0.13.3.1/Setup.hs:8:29: error:
        • Couldn't match expected type ‘Distribution.Simple.UserHooks.UserHooks’
                      with actual type ‘Cabal-1.24.1.0:Distribution.Simple.UserHooks.UserHooks’
          NB: ‘Cabal-1.24.1.0:Distribution.Simple.UserHooks.UserHooks’
                is defined in ‘Distribution.Simple.UserHooks’
                    in package ‘Cabal-1.24.1.0’
              ‘Distribution.Simple.UserHooks.UserHooks’
                is defined in ‘Distribution.Simple.UserHooks’
                    in package ‘Cabal-1.24.2.0’
        • In the first argument of ‘defaultMainWithHooks’, namely
            ‘gtk2hsUserHooks’
          In the expression: defaultMainWithHooks gtk2hsUserHooks
          In an equation for ‘main’:
              main = defaultMainWithHooks gtk2hsUserHooks
```

And chasing further, I tried to install gtk build tools:

```
$ stack install gtk2hs-buildtools
Copying from /home/username/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-7.10/8.0.1/bin/gtk2hsC2hs to /home/username/.local/bin/gtk2hsC2hs
Copying from /home/username/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-7.10/8.0.1/bin/gtk2hsHookGenerator to /home/username/.local/bin/gtk2hsHookGenerator
Copying from /home/username/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-7.10/8.0.1/bin/gtk2hsTypeGen to /home/username/.local/bin/gtk2hsTypeGen

Copied executables to /home/username/.local/bin:
- gtk2hsC2hs
- gtk2hsHookGenerator
- gtk2hsTypeGen
```

I kept getting the same error for cairo installation.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and do have `libcairo2-dev` installed:

```
$ stack install threadscope
glib-0.13.4.1: configure
cairo-0.13.3.1: configure
Progress: 2/6
--  While building package cairo-0.13.3.1 using:
      /home/username/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/bin/ghc --make -odir /tmp/stack20456/cairo-0.13.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup -hidir /tmp/stack20456/cairo-0.13.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup -i -i. -package=Cabal-1.24.2.0 -clear-package-db -global-package-db -package-db=/home/username/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-7.10/8.0.1/pkgdb /tmp/stack20456/cairo-0.13.3.1/Setup.hs /home/username/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -o /tmp/stack20456/cairo-0.13.3.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup -threaded
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Stack version:

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.3.2, Git revision 3f675146590da4f3edf768b89355f798229da2a5 (4395 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.15.0
```

Cabal version:

```
$ stack exec cabal -- --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.1
compiled using version 1.24.1.0 of the Cabal library
```

Other versions:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libglib2.0-dev libcairo2-dev libghc-gtk-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcairo2-dev is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-dev is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-dev set to manually installed.
libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version.
libgtk2.0-dev set to manually installed.
libpango1.0-dev is already the newest version.
libpango1.0-dev set to manually installed.
libghc-gtk-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
```

The reason I raise this here rather than superuser or ubuntu is that this error:

```
  • Couldn't match expected type ‘Distribution.Simple.UserHooks.UserHooks’
                  with actual type ‘Cabal-1.24.1.0:Distribution.Simple.UserHooks.UserHooks’
```

Does seem to suggest there's something funky with the Haskell package code itself expecting this to be within a module that is somehow one level deeper, inside the cabal-*:, right?

Other references that haven't cleared it up:

- [Building project dependent on gtk2hs fails on lts-7.8 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659148/building-project-dependent-on-gtk2hs-fails-on-lts-7-8-and-later)
- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2924
- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2230
- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2795
- [Missing dependencies for chart-cairo on linux mint 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240733/missing-dependencies-for-chart-cairo-on-linux-mint-17)

Comment: Can you try installing the development version of Stack (via `stack upgrade --git --source-only`)? There's support for the new `custom-setup` stuff in Cabal in the newest version. Also, `stack setup --upgrade-cabal` may help by providing the latest Cabal library, but is probably not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelSnoyman.  Is there documentation for the new custom-setup stuff?  Googling only gave me github bug reports.  Also, the first error I got after executing `stack upgrade --git --source-only` was `Cabal file warning in /tmp/stack-upgrade25291/stack/stack.cabal: Ignoring unknown section type: custom-setup` which does not bode well.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman, I installed with `stack upgrade --git --source-only` and still get the same errors in installing cairo, threadscope, and gtk2hs-buildtools.

Comment: This appears to be the official [custom-setup documentation](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#custom-setup-scripts). It's part of Cabal, not Stack. Regarding the Stack upgrade: can you confirm what `stack --version` now says?

Comment: `$ stack --version
Version 1.3.2, Git revision 3f675146590da4f3edf768b89355f798229da2a5 (4395 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.15.0` Huh. It did a bunch of installing when I ran that git command, but this is identical to the version I had beforehand.

Comment: I'm gonna guess you don't have ~/.local/bin in your $PATH. You should have gotten a warning message about that during the upgrade. Can you try running `~/.local/bin/stack --version`? And then try `~/.local/bin/stack build cairo`?

Comment: Ughhhh, I had /home/username/.cabal/bin/ on my path first... Completely, contravening your orders in:  https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#upgrade
and https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/237#issuecomment-126793301
Thanks @MichaelSnoyman.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. I'll create an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compile `cairo` successfully, you'll need support for the new [custom-setup feature in Cabal 1.24](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#custom-setup-scripts). The officially released Stack version does not support this yet, but support is available on `master`. In order to install it:

- Run `stack upgrade --git --source-only`
- Ensure that the destination directory (usually `$HOME/.local/bin`) is on your `PATH`
- To be extra sure, run `stack --version` and `which stack`

After this, `stack build cairo` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same problem I have [recently](https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/issues/198)

Could you try

`stack setup --upgrade-cabal`

and see if it fix the problem.

*== Edit: ==*

However, to answer your first question, I can install threadscope via stack with following command,

```
$ stack --resolver=nightly install threadscope
Selected resolver: nightly-2017-01-31
Copying from /home/wizzup/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-ncurses6/nightly-2017-01-31/8.0.2/bin/threadscope to /home/wizzup/.local/bin/threadscope

Copied executables to /home/wizzup/.local/bin/:
- threadscope
```

but I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: `$ stack setup --upgrade-cabal
Currently installed Cabal is 1.24.2.0, newest is 1.24.2.0. I'm not upgrading Cabal.`